# How to check this table column $value is it has the $value on the other table column in laravel

Tags: laravel

**This is my member's `light` table**

0 mean no light, 1 mean light on

```
|id| sx_ID | gylight| 
---------------------
|1 |SX00001|    0   |
|2 |SX00002|    1   |
|3 |SX00003|    1   | 
---------------------
```

**This is my `gylight` table**

When the member buy the light, it will save the `sx_ID` and other value to `gylight` table. Next, one member can buy more than one light.

```
|id| sx_ID | gylight_number| 
----------------------------
|1 |SX00002|    A1         |
|2 |SX00002|    A15        |
|3 |SX00003|    A78        | 
----------------------------
```

**This is my controller of delete function**

When admin delete the wrong record or old record, the `gylight` column in the `light` table should be update to `0`. But this coding will direct make the `gylight` become `0` , even the member still had other light. How can I write the code to check the light table's `sx_ID` is it has the `sx_ID` in the `gylight` table or other methods.

```
public function del(Request $request)
{   
    Guanyin::find($request->id)->delete();

    Light::where('sx_ID','=',$request->sx_ID)
           ->update(['gylight' => 0]);
    
    return response()->json();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eloquent, try this:

**Light Model**

```
public function guanyins()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Guanyin::class, 'sx_ID')
}
```

**Guanyin Model**

```
public function light()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Light::class, 'sx_ID');
}
```

**Guanyin Controller**

```
public function del(Request $request)
{   
    Guanyin::find($request->id)->delete();

    Light::where('sx_ID', '=', $request->sx_ID)
           ->whereDoesntHave('guanyins')
           ->update(['gylight' => 0]);
    
    return response()->json();
}
```

Comment: These code look like not working in my coding, when I try to delete all the result of the SX00002 in `gylight` table , but in the `light` table's  `gylight` there is no update

Comment: @JeremyYx My mistake, should using whereDoesntHave() that mean there is not Guanyin can be found by the sx_ID of Light result.

Comment: its working! But the `light` model should be  `return $this->hasMany(Guanyin::class, 'sx_ID', 'sx_ID');`

Answer (score 1):

You could use Observer to make this automatically, so you dont have do it manually, it would automatically update the **Light** whenever a **Guanyin** was deleted

**Light Model**

```
public function guanyins()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Guanyin::class, 'sx_ID')
}
```

**GuanyinModel**

```
use App\Observers\GuanyinObserver;

public function light()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Light::class, 'sx_ID');
}

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Guanyin::observe(GuanyinObserver::class);
}
```

**GuayinController**

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{   
    $guanyin = Guanyin::findOrFail($request->id);
    $guanyin->delete();
    return response()->json();
}
```

And to create the Observer you can run this command:

```
php artisan make:observer GuanyinObserver --model=Guanyin
```

reference : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

**GuanyinObserver**
and your observer code would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Guanyin;

class GuanyinObserver
{
     /**
     * Handle the guanyin "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Guanyin  $guanyin
     * @return void
     */
     public function deleted(Guanyin $guanyin)
     {
        $light = $guanyin->light;
        if($light->guanyins->count() == 0) {
             $light->gylight = 0;
             $light->update();
        }
     }
}
```

and you're done, now whenever a guanyin is deleted, it would check automatically for the light, count its guanyins, if count is 0, it switch gylight to 0
you can also apply this on **created**  method in observer, to change gylight to 1 whenever a guanyin is created

Comment: Hi , I try to use this coding but seen like it not working. Since I'm still a laravel novice, maybe I don't know this part well enough

Comment: @JeremyYx please refer to the edit I made above on GuanyinModel code